# posets, ordinal product and set of order preserving maths

Tags: combinatorics

In Stanley's book Enumerative Combinatorics, I came across those two exercises which are on the same chapter.

1. If $P,Q$ are graded posets and $Q$ has rank $r$ then $P \otimes Q$ is a  graded poset and
   $F(P \otimes Q, q) = F(P, q^{r+1})F(Q, q)$ where $F$ the rank generating function
2. Let $Q^P$ be the poset of order preserving functions defining $f\leq g$ iff $f(t)\leq g(t)$ for all $t\in P$.Then:

   i)$+$ and $\times$ are associative and commutative

   ii) $P \times (Q + R)$ is isomorphic to $(P \times Q) + (P \times R)$

   iii) $R^{(P+Q)}$ isomorphic  to $R^P \times R^Q$

   iv) $(R^Q)^P$ to $R^{Q\times R}$

It says that they are elementary but I got a bit confused,
any explanations, hint, thoughts or answers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint for part (1):

$P \otimes Q$ is defined as $\{(s,t) : s \in P \text{ and } t \in Q\}$ with $(s,t) \leq (s',t')$ if (a) $s = s'$ and $t \leq t'$ or (b) $s < s'$.  Now, let $(s,t) \in P \otimes Q$.  If we let $(s_0,t_0)$ be a minimal element in $P \otimes Q$ with $(s_0,t_0) \leq (s,t)$, try to show that each maximal chain from $(s_0,t_0)$ to $(s,t)$ has the same length.  To do so, utilize the fact that each maximal chain from $s_0$ to $s$ in $P$ has a fixed length, and the same from $t_0$ to $t$ in $Q$.  Once you have these two chains in $P$ and $Q$, how can you construct one in $P \otimes Q$?  What is its length?  Use this to compute the rank polynomial.

For (2), try to construct explicit isomorphisms.  I'll give you an example, by doing (iii).

Let $f \in R^{P+Q}$.  Then we see that $f|_{P} \in R^P$ and $f|_{Q} \in R^Q$.  Thus, the map $f \mapsto (f|_P,f|_Q)$ is a map from $R^{P+Q} \to R^P \times R^Q$.  It's not too bad to see that this is a bijection (it is reversible), and it's similarly not too bad to see that it is a poset isomorphism.  Try to come up with maps for each of these identities.  Write down the definitions for each and they'll become more clear.

Comment: Thank you. Should I proceed like I had for example P+Q where we have length=rankP+rankQ ?